# Backup and Restore Windows on Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, backup, vmware, restore

What if I make backup of Windows XP (say, with Acronis) on VMware and store it on shared folders with original Windows and after restore this backup on my Windows XP installed on hard drive? Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work because of difference between virtual hardware in your VMware virtual machine and real hardware.

Windows is choosing proper chipset drivers during installation and it's very hard (if not impossible) to change them later.